# can we switch two same route53 record set from primary to secondary using lambda python or any alternate?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, recordset

I have two route 53 record set URL with same name, type CNAME, pointing to different DNS and each has its own route 53 health check. Can I switch the record set failover case from primary to secondary and secondary to primary using lambda function/python or any best suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You sure can!

Using boto3 in your lambda function, you can use the [change_resource_record_sets](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets) method.

The key is to use the `UPSERT` action.

Here is an example you could incorporate into your lambda function (not tested)

```
import boto3

route53 = boto3.client('route53')

response = client.change_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId='ABCD12345',
    ChangeBatch={
        'Changes': [
            {
                "Action": "UPSERT",
                "ResourceRecordSet": {
                    "Type": "CNAME",
                    "Name": "example.com.",
                    "Failover": "PRIMARY",
                    "SetIdentifier": "example.com.Primary",
                    "ResourceRecords": [
                        {
                            "Value": "123.123.123.123"  # Primary IP
                        }
                    ]

                }
            },
            {
                "Action": "UPSERT",
                "ResourceRecordSet": {
                    "Type": "CNAME",
                    "Name": "example.com.",
                    "Failover": "SECONDARY",
                    "SetIdentifier": "example.com.Secondary",
                    "ResourceRecords": [
                        {
                            "Value": "123.123.123.321"  # failover IP
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```